# How to add more line item that show image and image detail after submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]
This is what I suppose it to be (with showing Floor name under image). How can I make it show the image with detail and close button after click submit?

```js
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = firstname;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```html
<h3>First name:</h3> <br>
<select>
  <option value="1">Floor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Floor 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Floor name" />
<input type="file" id="firstname">
<br>
<p>Your first name is: <b id='boldStuff2'></b> 
</p>

<ol id="demo"></ol>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Submit' />
```

Comment: Is there a server-side scripting language you can utilize, e.g. PHP, NodeJS, Ruby On Rails, C#, python, etc. for uploading the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the image asynchronously using a JavaScript function. Because you included the jQuery tag, here is an example with jQuery. It uses [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to upload the file, [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the newly uploaded image to the page.

```
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = firstname;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/museum/uploadImage.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        //Ajax events
        success: completeHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
function completeHandler(data) {
        if (data.result) {
                if (data.result[0] == '/') {
                     var newImage = $('<img>',{
                             src: data.result
                     });
                     var closeLink = $('<span>', {class: "closeImage"});
                     var container = $('<span>').append(closeLink, newImage);                                     
                     $('#uploadedImages').append(container);
                }
                else {
                        $('#errorMsg').html(data.result);
                }
        }
}
```

I applied those functions to the sample in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously#answer-8758614) and connected it with the PHP code below to handle uploading the image and returning the path to the image. See it in action on [my site](http://elliott.andrewz.org/museum/demo.html). It uses [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) to ensure the uploaded file is an image file (by checking the MIME-Type) with an image extension (adjust accordingly) and [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) to handle moving the temporary file to a path to store uploaded files.

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/upload_dir';
$output = array();
if (is_array($_FILES) && array_key_exists('image',$_FILES)) {
        $upload = $_FILES['image'];
    if ($upload['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && 
            preg_match('#^image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$#',$upload['type']) && //ensure mime-type is image
            preg_match('#.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$#',$upload['name']) //ensure name ends in trusted extension

    ) {
        $tmp_name = $upload["tmp_name"];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $parts = explode('/',$upload['tmp_name']);
        $tmpName = array_pop($parts);
        $name = $tmpName.'_'.basename($upload["name"]);
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name")) {
                $output['result'] = '/museum/'.$name;
        }
        else {
                $output['result'] = 'upload fail';
        }
    }
    else {
         $output['result'] = 'invalid image';
    }   
}
else {
        $output['result'] = 'no file selected';
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

After selecting an image and clicking the *Submit* button, the image is uploaded and the uploaded image is displayed with the image to close it.

[image]

For the close links, add an Event delegate like the one in the javascript below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
  $(document).click(function(clickEvent) {
    if ($(clickEvent.target).hasClass('closeImage')) {
      clickEvent.target.parentNode.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.closeImage {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url(https://www.secretsof.com/images/close_x.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="uploadedImages"><span><span class="closeImage"></span>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J15os.png">
  </span>
</div>
```